# iPhone... Pause current thread between actions (non blocking)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I have a function that selects a row on a `UITableView` and then fires `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to emulate the row having been clicked.  This all happens very fast making it hard to see what has happened, I want to artificially pause between these actions so that it is more pleasing to the eye.

I implemented this using `NSTimer` using the following code however it only has a resolution as low as 1 second. I would ideally like to pause around 300 ms.  How can I achieve as simply as possible?

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree with calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath directly. I would suggest moving whatever you're doing in there to a separate method (say, `selectionResponse:`) and calling that directly.

Once you've done this, you can use **`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`** to call your `selectionResponse:` method, setting the `afterDelay:` argument to whatever value you want.

The link for the documentation on `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_)

**Note that** it's also a good idea to use `+ cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` (from the same document) in your dealloc, to cancel a pending perform request if your user chooses to back out of your view controller within the delay period, before the selector is invoked. This will prevent a crash.